# How to do mesh analysis when 2 mesh are sharing the same voltage?

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws, superposition

I was doing superposition theorem and trying new numericals and then I came across this problem..should I write "9 volts or 9(IsubA-IsubB)" in mesh 1?[image]

Comment: Use 9 volts. What do you sum up when you use KVL? Also, what do you mean by using 9(Ia - Ib)? Voltage times current is power.

Comment: Thanks a lot..I got confused just because 2 mesh sharing the same voltage